# fixed size header in css styles

Tags: css, styles

I have written this styles: 
but it doesnt works well in **IE**

it appear in **IE** like this: http://fb812yh3737x2812.byethost3.com/IE.png

but i wanna be like this in **chrome** :  http://fb812yh3737x2812.byethost3.com/chr.png

```
/*css template designed by AmzMohammad*/
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/img01.jpg) repeat left top;
    font: 14px B Nazanin, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #212121;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.0em;
}

h5 {
    font: 45px "IranNastaliq","B Nazanin" ,Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h7 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font: 33px "Forte","Times New Roman (Headings CS)","Times Roman","Arial (Body CS)","Adobe Caslon Pro Bold","Agency FB","arial", Helvetica , sans-serif ;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

p, ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    line-height: 160%;
}

a {
    color: #393939;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #393939;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background: #393939;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #393939;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 375px;
    padding-right: 275px;
    background: url(images/head.jpg) no-repeat left 100% ;
}

#logo h1, #logo p {
    margin: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #393939;
}

#logo p {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#logo h1 {
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logo h5 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logo h7 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logo h4 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logo a {
    color: #393939;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 900px;
    background: #393939;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;

}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    font: 120% "B zar" ,"Adobe Arabic";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #393939;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #393939;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background: #cff;
    color:#393939;
    color:#393939;
}

#menu .first {
    background: none;
}

#menu .active a {
}

/* Page */

#page {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 3px auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}

/* Content */

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 570px;
}

.post {
    margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.post .title {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: #BFC9AE dashed 1px;
    color: #232F01;
}

.post .title a {
    color: #232F01;
}

.post .entry {
}

.post .meta {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.post .byline {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#sidebar-bgtop {
    height: 3px;
}

#sidebar-bgbtm {
    height: 3px;
}

#sidebar-content {
    padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li ul {
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li li {
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom: #BFC9AE dashed 1px;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    padding: 4px 20px;
    background: #393939;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #232F01;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#sidebar h6 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/* Search */

#search {
}

#search form {
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
    padding: 0px;
}

#search fieldset {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

#search #s {
    width: 160px;
}

/* Footer */

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #393939;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 19px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: smaller;
}

#footer a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

cheers

the html of header :

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h7 align="center">Mohammad Mahmoodi</h7>
        <p>Department of Computer Engineering, Faculty of Engineering, University of Isfahan</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end #logo -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Teaching.html">Teaching & Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
            <li><a href="students.html">Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="RI.html">Research Interests</a></li>
            <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
            <li><a href="other.html">attraction point</a></li>
            <li><a href="font.html">Font</a></li>
            <li><a href="farsi.html">Farsi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
</div>
```

Comment: I agree! but My user may use IE !

Comment: Can you please include the HTML for the **just** the header? Also, the `font` attribute in the `body` selector is incorrect, you forgot to quote 'B Nazanin`

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded that font, (because I assume that's not a standard font) it may have come in .TTF format, IE doesn't always recognise these files try converting it to .EOT and embed it on the site for more modern versions of IE compatibility. 
This generally only works for IE but i suppose if chrome is already recognising it you will most probably be OK for other browser

Comment: how embed the font on the site ?

Comment: @font-face {
    font-family: your font;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url(yourfont.eot);

Comment: and obviously have the font in the same folder as your main .html

Comment: I mixed up ! i have convert the font "forte.ttf" to "forte.eot". but dont know where write this code ?

Comment: the code I supplied goes into your .css file. but you will still need to use the .ttf as well just as you were to make sure that other browsers can still recognise it too.

Comment: other browsers shouldn't cause you a problem its just IE

Comment: and I want the header fully showed not depend on font ! how can I do it ?